# Modal not showing Menu Data

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to make a sample React Modal of Menu in which it must display Menu. So, I already developed its Backend using NodeJS + Express and it works properly. But, after I integrate it to Frontend Page, it does not show any menu data.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Tab, Tabs, TabList, TabPanel} from 'react-tabs';
import 'react-tabs/style/react-tabs.css';
import '../Styles/RestDetails.css';
import {Button} from 'react-bootstrap';
import Modal from 'react-modal';
import axios from 'axios';
import QueryString from 'query-string';

class RestDetails extends React.Component
{
    constructor()
    {
        super();
        this.state = {
            menus: [],
            isModalOpen: false
        }
    }
    componentDidMount()
    {
        const Qparams = QueryString.parse(this.props.location.search);
        const restID = Qparams.id;
        
        axios({
            method: 'GET',
            url: `http://localhost:4005/api/restaurantMenu/${restID}`,
            headers: {'Content-Type' : 'application/json'}
        }).then(result => {
            this.setState({
                menus: result.data.menus
            })
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
    handleOrder = (event) => {
        const {menus} = this.state;
        this.setState({
            isModalOpen: true
        });
    }
    cancelHandler = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            isModalOpen: false
        });
    }
    render()
    {
        const {isModalOpen, menus} = this.state;
        return(
            <div className="container-fluid">

                <div className="row">
                
                <Modal isOpen={isModalOpen} className="modal-dialog modal-lg" id="modal_header">
                        <div className="modal-content">
                            <div className="modal-header">
                                <h3 className="modal-title">MENU</h3>
                                <button type="button" className="close" onClick={this.cancelHandler}>&times;</button>
                            </div>
                            <div className="modal-body">
                                <table className="table table-bordered">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                        {
                                            menus.map((item, index) => {
                                                return (
                                                    <div className="row">
                                                        <td>
                                                        <div className="col-6">{item.item}</div>
                                                        <div className="col-2">{item.cost}</div>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                        <div className="col-4"><Button>ADD</Button></div>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <hr/>
                                                    </div>
                                                )
                                            })
                                        }
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                            <div className="modal-footer">
                                <div className="float-left">Subtotal: 220</div>
                                <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.Handler}>Order</button>
                                <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={this.cancelHandler}>Cancel</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </Modal>

                </div>
            
        )
    }    
}   

export default RestDetails;
```

Here, the Modal is linked with Button using State Handler and componentDidMount() which is linked to Backend using Axios and Query-String. I checked the Backend using Postman and it able to fetch and display data by entering the restaurant ID. But it can't able to display at the Frontend Modal. Please share some ideas. Thanks in advance.